# Ext JS - Cannot get textfield label to show in column layout

Tags: extjs

Inside my FormPanel , I have a fieldset with a layout of 'column'.
I have tried several different config properties but  i cannot get the label for my textfield to work. It just renders the textbox without a label.
(Obviously, if i make the layout type 'form', i have no issues). The text for the checkboxes shows fine, but the textbox label does not. Can someone point out what is wrong ?
thanks!

```
xtype:'fieldset',
title:'Transaction Status',
layout: 'column',
style:'margin:5px;'
,height:125//or:'-20', allowBlank:false}
,defaultType: 'checkbox'            
,defaults: {
        columnWidth: '.32',
        border: false
          },            

 items: [{
        id:'check1-field',
            name: 'check1',
            boxLabel: 'DOT'
         },{
            id:'check2-field',
            boxLabel: 'Results Matched',
            name: 'check2'
          },{
            xtype:'textfield',
            name: 'testname',                 
            fieldLabel:'This doesnt show'
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ext Docs for TextField](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/ext-2.2.1/docs/output/Ext.Component.html#fieldLabel)

***"This config is only used when this Component is rendered by a Container which has been configured to use the FormLayout layout manager."***

So, since you have a layout of "column", I don't think it will render.

Best best is probably to place your check boxes in a separate field set below the text entry boxes, or just remove the column layout style and change it to form (the default).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with you..

I solved it using panel xtype.

set your checkboxes becomes the items of a panel.